# Create a Pandas Dataframe from nested dict

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a nested dict with following structure: 
course_id, nested dict with: 2 recommended courses and number of purchases for every course.
For example entries of this dict look smth like this:

```
 {490: {566: 253, 551: 247},
 357: {571: 112, 356: 100},
 507: {570: 172, 752: 150}}
```

I tried this code to make a dataframe from this dict:

```
result=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dicts, orient='index').stack().reset_index()
result.columns=['Course ID','Recommended course','Number of purchases']
```

[image: Pls. see the output]

This doesn't quite work for me, because I want an output where there will be 5 columns. 
Course ID, recommended course 1, purchases 1, recommended course 2, purchases 2.
Is there any solution for this? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show what the expect output looks like with a synthetic dataframe.

Comment: Yes, and please explain what is what in the nested dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you just re-shape your dictionary then re-create your dataframe, however you're not far off from getting your target output from your current dataframe.

we can `groupby` and use `cumcount` to create our unique column then `unstack` and assign our column from the multi index header that was created.

```
s1 = result.groupby(['Course ID',
             result.groupby(['Course ID']).cumcount() + 1]).first().unstack()

s1.columns = [f"{x}_{y}" for x,y in s1.columns]


              Recommended course_1  Recommended course_2  Number of purchases_1  \
Course ID                                                                      
357                         571                   356                  112.0   
490                         566                   551                  253.0   
507                         570                   752                  172.0   

           Number of purchases_2  
Course ID                         
357                        100.0  
490                        247.0  
507                        150.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Not an efficient one, but should work in your case:-

```
df = pd.DataFrame([(k,list(v.keys())[0],list(v.values())[0],list(v.keys())[1],list(v.values())[1]) for k,v in a.items()], columns = ['Course ID','Recommended course 1','purchases 1', 'Recommended Course 2', 'purchases 2'])
print(df)
```

Output:-

```
   Course ID  Recommended course 1  purchases 1  Recommended Course 2  \
0        490                   566          253                   551
1        357                   571          112                   356
2        507                   570          172                   752

   purchases 2
0          247
1          100
2          150
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use itertools chain to convert the nested dict into a flat list of key, value pairs, and store into a dictionary `d2` using dictionary comprehension where the keys are the course id, and then proceed with forming the dataframe using pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import chain

d = {
    490: {566: 253, 551: 247},
    357: {571: 112, 356: 100},
    507: {570: 172, 752: 150}
}

d2 = {k: list(chain.from_iterable(v.items())) for k, v in d.items()}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d2, orient='index').reset_index()
df.columns = ['id','rec_course1', 'n_purch_1', 'rec_course2', 'n_purch_2']
```

df

```
    id   rec_course1  n_purch_1  rec_course2  n_purch_2
0  490           566        253          551        247
1  357           571        112          356        100
2  507           570        172          752        150
```